# Keeping value of p:calendar date after selection of an item of h:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, calendar

I have a h:selectOneMenu and a p:calendar which may be disabled depending on the select item chosen.

The problem is : if I first select the item value b, click on the calendar to choose a date different than today, select the item value c, then the date is reset to initial value. How can I keep the selected date ?

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{mb.selectedTypeMessage}" style="min-width: 250px;">
         <f:selectItem id="type1" itemLabel="a" itemValue="a" /> 
         <f:selectItem id="type2" itemLabel="b" itemValue="b" />  
         <f:selectItem id="type3" itemLabel="c" itemValue="c" />
         <f:ajax render="button" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<p:calendar id="button" value="#{mb.selectedIncidentDate}" disabled="#{mb.selectedTypeMessage eq a}" showOn="button"/>


@ManagedBean(name = "mb")
@ViewScoped
public class MessageBean implements Serializable {
   private String selectedTypeMessage;
   private String selectedSector;
   private Date selectedIncidentDate;
  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
       this.selectedIncidentDate = new Date();
       this.selectedTypeMessage = "a";
  }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a `p:ajax` on the calendar. That should update the value on the bean.

```
<p:calendar ...>
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" />
</p:calendar>
```